# Closure Question - What is the JavaScript statement to call a function that is returned from an enclosing function?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using a closure as seen below, but I want to try to call `myFunction()` from another place of code.  What JS statement is required to invoke the anonymous function expression that is returned from the enclosing function labeled `handleMouseDown()`?     Currently handleMouseDown() is not being invoked on a mouseDown event on a select dropdown list that bind to the mouseDown.

```
function handleMouseDown(whichDropDown) {
            if (typeof mouseDownCount === 'undefined')
                mouseDownCount = 0;
            return function(whichDropDown, mouseDownCount) {
                switch (mouseDownCount) {
                    case 0:
                        mouseDownCount++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mouseDownCount++;
                        myFunction(whichDropDown);
                        break;
                }
                return mouseDownCount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `callback(someArg, 1)` should work..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, may I request a formal answer, to clarify if this is the only method of approach?  I appreciate the hint of approach, thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what the callback is actually doing, how it works in the case of my closure, because I know of callbacks that are invoked when a process completes?

Comment: The callback is just this function that was returned: `return function(whichDropDown, mouseDownCount) {` Calling the callback just invokes that function. First argument passed will be `whichDropDown`. Second argument passed will be `mouseDownCount`. Since the `switch` depends on `mouseDownCount`, you just need to pass the proper second parameter to get the `myFunction` invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, the only thing required for `myFunction` to be invoked looks to be the passing of `1` as an argument to the callback returned from `handleMouseDown`:

```js
const myFunction = arg => console.log('myFunction called with', arg);

function handleMouseDown(whichDropDown) {
  if (typeof mouseDownCount === 'undefined')
    mouseDownCount = 0;
  return function(whichDropDown, mouseDownCount) {
    switch (mouseDownCount) {
      case 0:
        mouseDownCount++;
        break;
      case 1:
        mouseDownCount++;
        myFunction(whichDropDown);
        break;
    }
    return mouseDownCount;
  }
}

const callback = handleMouseDown('someDropdown');
callback('foo', 1);
```

Keep in mind that you appear to have two separate bindings for `mouseDownCount` - one looks to be an outer or global variable (not declared), and the other is the second argument passed to the callback. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to implement there, but make sure you understand the difference, it'll probably be an easy source of bugs.

If you just want to call something on the second click of an element, it would be far easier just to have a variable that keeps track of the number of clicks:

```js
let clickCount = 0;
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click detected');
  clickCount++;
  if (clickCount === 2) {
    console.log('second click');
  }
});
```

Comment: My objective is to provide a means to call myFunction on second mouse click, that is when the user clicks on the drop down option and if the option value chagnes.